# Crosstabs Crystal Reports Null value vs zero

Tags: crystal-reports, null, crosstab, zero

I'm creating a crosstab report showing the survey history for gopher tortoises ([if you must know what that is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_tortoise)) monitoring stations.  Not all stations are monitored for a given survey and sometimes when we monitor we don't find any and thus record a 0 which is a valid result.

In the crosstab when the station isn't used I would like it to say "N/A" or some other equivalent, but when it's a zero I want it to stay as zero.

I've found so much on how to change a null to a zero, but nothing when you want to keep the zero and somehow note the null.

Below is what the crosstab should look like.  You'll see that the 0 in Station4 on 1/1/2004 is "real" (meaning we didn't find any) but all of the N/A's are when we didn't use the station.

```
                          Survey Dates
|          | 1/1/2000 | 1/1/2002 | 1/1/2004 | 1/1/2006 |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| Station1 | 9        | 5        | N/A      | N/A      |
| Station2 | 5        | 7        | 2        | 6        |
| Station3 | N/A      | N/A      | 6        | 9        |
| Station4 | 10       | 9        | 0        | 11       |
```

This is what the Oracle table look like for the 1/1/2000 survey as an example

```
| SurveyID | StationID | Number |
|----------|-----------|--------|
| 1        | 1         | 9      |
| 1        | 2         | 5      |
| 1        | 4         | 6      |
```

So, basically how to I keep the zero's and put some text in the nulls in a CR crosstab?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you summing these survey numbers anywhere in the crosstab? Put another way, does each station only have a single value in the database for each column in your crosstab?

Comment: Actually no...I tried to keep it simple since I didn't think it mattered.  The Oracle table actually looks like

Comment: Let me start my comment over since I was interrupted and I passed the 5 minute mark...@ryan Thanks for the response. Actually no...I tried to keep it simple since I didn't think it mattered.  The Oracle table actually has two "number" fields (one for active burrows and other for inactive burrows).  I then did created a formula field that summed those two fields.  It's that formula field that I included in the crosstab.  However, I also created another report where I put both of the inactive and active fields separately in the crosstab and I'm still having that same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because CR doesn't differentiate between nulls and actual zeros in the crosstab, you can try replacing actual zero values with a placeholder so you can tell the difference. Note that this solution will only work if you are trying to display the values and not do any aggregate calculations.

First, create a formula that will replace the zeros with a placeholder value. In this case, I'm using -1 since that number should never appear in the database.

```
    //{@Survey Num}
    local numbervar totalSurvey;
    totalSurvey:={Table.ActiveBurrows} + {Table.InactiveBurrows};
    if totalSurvey=0 then -1 else totalSurvey
```

Use this formula to create your crosstab. Now you need to set a display string so that everything appears correctly. Right-click one of your crosstab cells → hit "Format Field" → select the "Common" tab → then create a "Display String" formula. That formula should be something like:

```
if currentfieldvalue=-1 then "0" else if currentfieldvalue=0 then "N/A" else totext(currentfieldvalue,0,'')
```

Now you're basically just printing the real values over top of the placeholders.

Comment: Oh thank you @ryan! I had the same issue and am searching the archives, but this gave me exactly what I needed!